# разбивка сайта по файлам JavaEE

Tags: java-ee, jsp, шаблоны, jstl

Решил разбить сайт на файлы template. И столкнулся с такой проблемой. Я хочу вынести в отдельный файл `head` страницы, но на разных страницах у меня подключаются разные стили, разные заголовки и описание. я использую JSP. я мог бы передать параметры в head файл при помощи `jstl` но та страница не jsp она тегов не понимает. Подскажите пожалуйста если какой-то выход? может посоветуете что-то